# Print JSON value using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I am trying to print some data from a JSON end point using AngularJS.
End point :- `http://localhost:8081/api`

JSON structure :-

```
{
  "1": {
    "venture": "XYZ Informatics",
    "member": [
      {
        "name": "abcd",
        "email": "abcd@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "message": "This is good day",
    "isclicked": false
  },
  "2": {
    "venture": "BBC Informatics",
    "member": [
      {
        "name": "xyz",
        "email": "xyz@gmail.com"
      }
    ],
    "message": "This is bad day",
    "isclicked": false
  }
}
```

I want to display the name of venture s in row. My expected output in row is :-

```
XYZ Informatics
BBC Informatics
```

My Code is :-

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse;
      }
      th, td {
      padding: 15px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="displayController">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr ng-repeat="data in datas">
          <td>{{ data.venture }}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script>
      angular.module('MyApp', [])
      .controller('displayController', function($scope, $http) {
      var url = "http://localhost:8081/api";
      $http.get(url).success(function (response) {
      $scope.datas = response;
      });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But the value is not displaying. Probably, I am missing to get into each array of JSON.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a syntax error on your script. Close the brackets for your controller.

```
  <script>
    angular.module('MyApp', [])
      .controller('displayController', function($scope, $http) {
        //changed to your local api
         var url = "http://localhost:8081/api";
        $http.get(url).success(function(response) {
          $scope.datas = response;
        });
      });//this is the place where you miss out the closing bracket
  </script>
```

Here is the working [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/X8L5WwbIVWNzjoLxoHTg?p=preview).